# how can i see Object box database in flutter?

Tags: database, flutter, offline, objectbox

I have made a flutter application and to store data in offline mode I use an object box database.

but now the issue is how can see what data are stored in a database. how many tables or entries are there?

i read documentation from the object box but like me who is fresher in it need some guidance or simple steps how can I see the object box database?

object box package : https://pub.dev/packages/objectbox

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for is this:

> [ObjectBox Admin Web App](https://docs.objectbox.io/data-browser)

you will need to do the required setup for, then get an `Admin` instance for your ObjectBox database with:

```
if (Admin.isAvailable()) {
  // Keep a reference until no longer needed or manually closed.
  admin = Admin(store);
}

// (Optional) Close at some later point.
admin.close();
```

Comment: Yes, I did that but I am not able to find how to see in mobile. there are some command like tcp8089 but didn;t get it in proper way. Could you please give explain in little bit more details how can i get it?

Comment: What part of the instructions at https://docs.objectbox.io/data-browser are not clear to you?